# Pandas dataframe duplicate rows with list separation in the class?

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, data-manipulation

I have a dataframe with rows/records like this:

### Data:

```
id age sex weight class
0  30  1   65     ['AA', 'BB']
1  40  0   76     ['AA', 'CC', 'DD']
```

My class is a list with more than one value, I want to duplicate the rows leaving a list value in each.

### Desired result:

```
id age sex weight class
0  30  1   65     ['AA']
1  30  1   65     ['BB']
2  40  0   76     ['AA']
3  40  0   76     ['CC']
4  40  0   76     ['DD']
```

How can I do this on an entire dataframe that has a rows structure like that?

the order of the ids does not matter much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `explode` the class column:

```
df2 = df.set_index('id').explode('class').reset_index(drop=True)
df2['class'] = df2['class'].apply(lambda x: [x])
df2
   age  sex  weight class
0   30    1      65  [AA]
1   30    1      65  [BB]
2   40    0      76  [AA]
3   40    0      76  [CC]
4   40    0      76  [DD]
```